# what is the start point to disassemble MIPS architecture(isa32r2)'s library?

Tags: c, gcc, mips

I use some third-party libraries in a project. 
This project is a embedded system with a MIPS(isa32r2) core. 
Recently we found a bug in the third-party library(libusb.a), but because of the time there is no technical support anymore. 
so I try to disassemble the libarary.

```
$ mips-sde-elf-ar -x libusb.a
$ mips-sde-elf-objdump.exe -Ds -mmips:isa32r2 -EL usbhost_func.o > usbhost_func.s
```

in file usbhost_func.s I can get some info like:

```
    Disassembly of section .text.usbhost_init:

    00000000 :
       0:   27bdffd8    addiu   sp,sp,-40
       4:   3c020000    lui v0,0x0
```

**.text.usbhost_init** looks like a complete disassembly functions of **usbhost_init()**.
but there is some other info here like:

```
    Disassembly of section .pdr:

    00000000 :
       0:   00000000    nop
       4:   40000000    mfc0    zero,c0_index
       8:   fffffffc    sdc3    $31,-4(ra)
        ...         why here is  ...
      14:   00000008    jr  zero
      18:   0000001e    0x1e
      1c:   0000001f    0x1f
      20:   00000000    nop


    Disassembly of section .gnu.attributes:

    00000000 :
       0:   00000f41    0xf41
       4:   756e6700    jalx    5b99c00 
       8:   00070100    sll zero,a3,0x4
       c:   03040000    0x3040000
```

so my question is:

> 1. What does the secton's mean like **section .pdr**?
> 2. Why there is some  **...**  in **setion .pdr** ?
> 3. What is the srart point to disassemble a mips library?
>      Any hint and info are welcome.Tks.

Answer (score 3):

1. `objdump -D` will try to deassemble all sections instead of sections which include valid instructions, you should use `objdump -d`.
2. `.pdr` is a debug information section, may not include valid instructions.
3. For static libraries (.a files), you should extract the object files in these libraries by `ar x libfoo.a`, and try to deassemble those object files you got by `objdump -d`.

Comment: after a google search, I found this [Use ".pdr" sections generated by GAS](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2002-06/msg00175.htm) `ECOFF debug information (mdebug) included the concept of a PDR.  MIPS uses
these for unwinding through functions, among other things.  Right now we can
get them from mdebug or from code inspection.  But current GNU binutils
emits ".pdr" sections instead of using the old ".mdebug" style debug info.`  **.pdr** settion is a debug information sectoin. thanks @leeduhem